# TFS 2015 change or disable $(BuldAgentID)

Tags: tfs

I'm using new tfs 2015 build agent (not XAML one). In XAML it was possible to change working path from `$(SystemDrive)\Builds\$(BuildAgentId)\$(BuildDefinitionPath)` to any.

Is it possible to change path in new agent to disable or lock `$(BuldAgentID)` ?

To disable generation of random digits like:

```
c:\Agent\work\1
c:\Agent\work\2
c:\Agent\work\3
etc.
```

Comment: I was trying to use Agent.BuildDirectory as param with value c:\Agent\work\100 but it hasn't helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the build variables to change the same,
The working directory for this agent. By default $(Agent.RootDirectory)_work.
now you can assign the variable to any location.
Check the [Link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/Library/vs/alm/Build/scripts/variables)

Comment: By default in settings.json it already in static, like    "WorkFolder": "C:\\Agent\\_work". Digits apends after it.

Comment: Wait i think the build directory is set when the Agent is configured for the first time. If that is the case i think you left that default. Which you can update by changing the agent.

Comment: I wondering how the agent is working. With Agent.WorkFolder="c:Agent\work\500"  as you recommend it indeed creates folder 500 with "SourceRootMapping" in it, but another folders like "a", "b", "s", "TestResultes" are still inside random generated digit folder )

Comment: please try with other variables from the link, i have not tried the same, you can check the Agent Build Variables section where it is mentioned about the  $(Agent.BuildDirectory)\b switch etc. Hope this helps.

Comment: I tryed to set Agent.BuildDirectory in params section, but resul was the same. So i've decided to use value of $(Agent.BuildDirectory) in my scripts to determine the correct path. Thx for your help.